# Updated content is not loading, when working with AJAX

Tags: ajax

i am working with CHARTS.

I am using a third party tool to create charts.
I am working with Asp.net AJAX, C#.

Chart loads properly during page load.
The data for the chart will be saved in an xml file and csv file. Later it will be passed to chart applet through a javascript file.
When i get a new set of data through new inputs, the data is getting updated in xml and csv file.

But finally when i am passing the csv and xml file path to javascript, it is displaying the page loaded content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a caching issue. Clear all cache and then verify.

If it is a caching issue the best possible way is to change the request string for every request. You can do this by appending a random number to the end of the querystring.

***Edit:***

Suppose your requect url is

```
var reqUrl = "http://host.com/mypage.html";
```

Then replace the request url string with something like

```
var rand = Math.random();
var reqUrl = "http://host.com/mypage.html?v0=" + rand;
```

Comment: I am not redirecting to any new page. Just i am binding new data based on some filter parameters(such as changing the from date and todate)

Comment: I am also not talking about redirecting to a new page. What happens to the result when you clear your cache?

Comment: I tried to clear page cache through a meta tag
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
But it didnt work.

How can i achieve this?
Appending a random number to the end of the querystring